# How does $x^3 - \sin^3 x$ become $x^3 + \frac{1}{4}\sin{3x}-\frac{3}{4}\sin x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was going through answers on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656757/evaluating-int-0-infty-fracx3-sin3xx5-dx-using-cont/877629#comment1811019_877629) and came across this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/784150/38296) and I was wondering how the user arrived at the first line where they state:

$$f(x) \equiv x^3 - \sin^3 x = x^3 + {1 \over 4} \,\sin {3x} - {3 \over 4}\,\sin x$$

> How does $x^3 - \sin^3 x$ become $x^3 + \frac{1}{4}\sin{3x}-\frac{3}{4}\sin x$?

Are they using some simple identity or is there some other observation happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to review your question for the correct statements.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't quite understand, can you please clarify?

Comment: You have $1\over 3$ at one place and $1\over 4$ at another.

Comment: Ahhh, fixed! Thanks!

Comment: Title is still wrong -- it has $\tfrac13$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from the rules for the [sine of the multiple of an angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles).

This can be derived from the fact that $e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ with $i=\sqrt{-1}$

We have $e^{i n\theta} = \cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$

But also $e^{i n\theta} = (\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n$

With the real and imaginary parts equated this gives us the formulas listed under the link.

(as hinted in another answer, we normally start with $\sin(n\theta)$ and get to a function involving $\sin^n(\theta)$ rather than the other way around)

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** $$\sin{3x}=3\sin {x} -4\sin^3 x \\ \sin {(A+B)}=\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

> $$\sin^3(x) =  \left(  \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \right)^3 = \dots\,. $$

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**
$$\sin x =\frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$$